# Spark-Csv Write quotemode not working

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write a DataFrame as a CSV file using Spark-CSV (https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)

I am using the command below

```
res1.write.option("quoteMode", "NONE").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("File")
```

But my CSV file is always written as

"London"
"Copenhagen"
"Moscow"

instead of

London
Copenhagen
Moscow

Comment: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: quoteMode  was never supported https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26968

Answer (score 20):

Yes. The way to turn off the default escaping of the double quote character (") with the backslash character (\), you must add an .option() method call with just the right parameters after the .write() method call. The goal of the option() method call is to change how the csv() method "finds" instances of the "quote" character. To do this, you must change the default of what a "quote" actually means; i.e. change the character sought from being a double quote character (") to a Unicode "\u0000" character (essentially providing the [Unicode NUL character](https://unicode-table.com/en/) which won't ever occur within a well formed JSON document).

```
val dataFrame =
  spark.sql("SELECT * FROM some_table_with_a_json_column")
val unitEmitCsv =
  dataframe
    .write
    .option("header", true)
    .option("delimiter", "\t")
    .option("quote", "\u0000") //magic is happening here
    .csv("/FileStore/temp.tsv")
```

This was only one of several lessons I learned attempting to work with Apache Spark and emitting .csv files. For more information and context on this, please see the blog post I wrote titled "[Example Apache Spark ETL Pipeline Integrating a SaaS](http://fromjavatoscala.blogspot.com/2017/03/example-apache-spark-etl-pipeline.html)".

Comment: what to do in case of a csv?
It writes that special character \u00 inside the file.

Comment: This solution _finds_ instance of character \u0000, not insert them unless it finds one. Then, it will insert a second \u0000 just prior to the found one to "escape" it. If your output contains any instances of \u0000, then you must choose a different value than \u0000 to pass to the function.

Comment: I suggest you try writing a dataframe value which contains double quotes in one of the columns. I said so because of the results I saw while writing not based on any theory.
If you could try first and then let me know if it is still valid.

Comment: I did. My column value contains JSON which is full of double quotes. I needed it to stop escaping those as I was writing a tab delimited line and needed the double quotes ignored. My solution ignores double quotes. Not sure what your trying to solve with this solution if it isn't related to _ignoring_ double quotes.

Comment: I just added in the explicit line where I am using tabs (not commas) as my column separator. I am not sure if that is something that will help you see what you need to see in my solution.

Comment: yep! it works with tab as delimiter but not otherwise.

Comment: It does not work with pipe or tab delimiter. I can see null char.

Comment: I got an error saying that "java.lang.RuntimeException: quote cannot be more than one character" on \u0000 do you know what it means?

Comment: I got the same "py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o156.csv.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: quote cannot be more than one character" error

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium You saved my day. After putting lot of efforts to finish the task, it doesn't work while writing to csv. Thanks for letting me know the "magic"

Answer (score 6):

The double quoting of the text can be removed by setting the `quoteAll` option to false

```
dataframe.write
 .option("quoteAll", "false")
 .format("csv")
```

This example is as per Spark 2.1.0 with out using the databricks lib.

Comment: Not working for me, the double quotes are still there.

Comment: Not work for me either. BTW, one typo, should be `option`, not `options`

Comment: this helped me removing the quotes from empty strings, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use option

```
.option("emptyValue", "")
```

That's in spark 2.4+

Comment: it works for me with the pipe delimiter, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If your DataFrame has a single string you can write out a text file directly.

```
df.coalesce(1).map({ k:Row => k(0).toString}).toJavaRDD.saveAsTextFile("File")
```

If you have multiple columns you can combine them as a single string before writing to the output file.

The other answers given may result in unwanted null or space characters being emitted in your output file.

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for my use case wherein i have to write a csv with each row being multiline string and no need for double quotes that spark was putting in.

Comment: this works well for single column items. thanks

Answer (score 1):

this problem bothers me for a long time until I read this: [Adding custom Delimiter adds double quotes in the final spark data frame CSV outpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002414/adding-custom-delimiter-adds-double-quotes-in-the-final-spark-data-frame-csv-out)

> This is a standard CSV feature. If there's an occurrence of delimiter in the actual data (referred to as Delimiter Collision), the field is enclosed in quotes.
>   You can try
>   df.write.option("delimiter" , somechar)
>   where somechar should be a character that doesn't occur in your data.

You can just concat multiple columns into one and use a delimiter that is not in your data

Answer (score 0):

There are some similar conditions I have ever been confuesd, Finally I find a sep parameter can change the result, you can try this:

```html
df.write.mode("overwrite").option("sep","\t").csv(path)
```

Answer (score -3):

I was able to turn that off by setting the quote option to be a single white space

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("quote"," ").option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").save("File path")
```

But this will just replace option which put space in place of quote (")

There is one more option i.e., quote generally occurs as qualifier to separate some column when delimiter and separator are same

so you can change delimiter and get rid of quote automatically

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").save("File path")
```

Hope this works in your case

Comment: Neither worked for me. See https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/291 for more discussion but as of yet no solution.

Comment: Your answer is actually not only incorrect, it causes the JSON content to become corrupt. So, while it might have solved a highly specific problem you had at the time you were doing this, it isn't a general solution. I have come up with a general solution which I cover in my own answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43129783/501113